# a simple implementation of unix2dos for windows

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, windows

On linux there is the utility called unix2dos which converts UNIX EOLs(\n) to DOS EOLs(\r\n). However on windows there is no such tool so as a result I decided to make one.

`unix2dos.c`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define chunksize (1 << 13)
#define nullptr ((void *)0)
uint8_t buffer[chunksize + 1] = { 0 };

int64_t newline_count(HANDLE filehandle)
{
    DWORD bytes_read = 0;
    int64_t result = 0;
    do
    {
        if (ReadFile(filehandle, buffer + 1, chunksize, &bytes_read, nullptr) == 0)
        {
            WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not read file", 26, nullptr, nullptr);
            ExitProcess(GetLastError());
        }

        if (SetFilePointerEx(filehandle, (LARGE_INTEGER) { .QuadPart = -1 }, nullptr, SEEK_CUR) == 0)
        {
            WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not read file", 26, nullptr, nullptr);
            ExitProcess(GetLastError());
        }

        if (ReadFile(filehandle, buffer, 1, nullptr, nullptr) == 0)
        {
            WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not read file", 26, nullptr, nullptr);
            ExitProcess(GetLastError());
        }

        if (SetFilePointerEx(filehandle, (LARGE_INTEGER) { .QuadPart = -1 }, nullptr, SEEK_CUR) == 0)
        {
            WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not read file", 26, nullptr, nullptr);
            ExitProcess(GetLastError());
        }

        for (uint8_t *start = buffer + 1; start != buffer + 1 + (int64_t)bytes_read; ++start)
        {
            if (start[0] == '\n' && start[-1] != '\r') ++result;
        }
    } while (bytes_read == chunksize);
    return result;
}

void unix2dos1(wchar_t const *const src, wchar_t const *const dst)
{
    HANDLE const dst_file = CreateFileW(dst, GENERIC_ALL, 0, nullptr, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    if (dst_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not open ", 22, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), dst, lstrlenW(dst), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    HANDLE const src_file = CreateFileW(src, GENERIC_READ, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    if (src_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not open ", 22, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), src, lstrlenW(src), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    int64_t invalid_newline_count = newline_count(src_file);

    LARGE_INTEGER end_locaition = { 0 };
    if (GetFileSizeEx(src_file, &end_locaition) == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(src_file);
        CloseHandle(dst_file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not get the size of ", 33, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), src, lstrlenW(src), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    if (SetFilePointerEx(dst_file, (LARGE_INTEGER) { .QuadPart = invalid_newline_count + end_locaition.QuadPart }, &end_locaition, FILE_BEGIN) == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(src_file);
        CloseHandle(dst_file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not resize ", 24, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), dst, lstrlenW(dst), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    if (SetEndOfFile(dst_file) == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(dst_file);
        CloseHandle(src_file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not resize ", 24, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), dst, lstrlenW(dst), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    HANDLE const dst_memory_mapped_file = CreateFileMappingW(
        dst_file,
        nullptr,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0, 0,
        nullptr
    );

    if (dst_memory_mapped_file == nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(src_file);
        CloseHandle(dst_file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not create file mapping object for ", 48, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), dst, lstrlenW(dst), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    HANDLE const src_memory_mapped_file = CreateFileMappingW(
        src_file,
        nullptr,
        PAGE_READONLY,
        0, 0,
        nullptr
    );


    if (src_memory_mapped_file == nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(dst_memory_mapped_file);
        CloseHandle(src_file);
        CloseHandle(dst_file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not create file mapping object for ", 48, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), src, lstrlenW(src), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    uint8_t *const src_file_buffer = MapViewOfFile(src_memory_mapped_file, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, end_locaition.QuadPart - invalid_newline_count);

    if (src_file_buffer == nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(dst_memory_mapped_file);
        CloseHandle(src_memory_mapped_file);
        CloseHandle(src_file);
        CloseHandle(dst_file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not map view of ", 29, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), src, lstrlenW(src), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }


    uint8_t *const dst_file_buffer = MapViewOfFile(dst_memory_mapped_file, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, end_locaition.QuadPart);

    if (dst_file_buffer == nullptr)
    {
        UnmapViewOfFile(src_file_buffer);
        CloseHandle(dst_memory_mapped_file);
        CloseHandle(src_memory_mapped_file);
        CloseHandle(src_file);
        CloseHandle(dst_file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not map view of ", 29, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), dst, lstrlenW(dst), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }


    uint8_t *start1 = src_file_buffer;
    uint8_t *start2 = dst_file_buffer;

    end_locaition.QuadPart -= invalid_newline_count;
    for (; end_locaition.QuadPart; ++start1, ++start2, --end_locaition.QuadPart)
    {
        if (start1[0] == '\n')
        {
            if (start1 - 1 <= src_file_buffer || start1[-1] != '\r')
            {
                *start2++ = '\r';
            }

        }
        start2[0] = start1[0];
    }

    UnmapViewOfFile(src_file_buffer);
    UnmapViewOfFile(dst_file_buffer);
    CloseHandle(dst_memory_mapped_file);
    CloseHandle(src_memory_mapped_file);
    CloseHandle(src_file);
    CloseHandle(dst_file);
}

void unix2dos2(const wchar_t *const filepath)
{
    HANDLE const file = CreateFileW(filepath, GENERIC_ALL, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not open ", 22, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), filepath, lstrlenW(filepath), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    int64_t invalid_newline_count = newline_count(file);
    if (invalid_newline_count == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return;
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER end_locaition = { 0 };
    if (SetFilePointerEx(file, (LARGE_INTEGER) { .QuadPart = invalid_newline_count }, &end_locaition, FILE_END) == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not resize ", 24, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), filepath, lstrlenW(filepath), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    if (SetEndOfFile(file) == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not resize ", 24, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), filepath, lstrlenW(filepath), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    HANDLE const memory_mapped_file = CreateFileMappingW(
        file,
        nullptr,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0, 0,
        nullptr
    );

    if (memory_mapped_file == nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not create file mapping object for ", 48, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), filepath, lstrlenW(filepath), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    uint8_t *const file_buffer = MapViewOfFile(memory_mapped_file, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, end_locaition.QuadPart);

    if (file_buffer == nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        CloseHandle(memory_mapped_file);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), L"Error: could not map view of ", 29, nullptr, nullptr);
        WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), filepath, lstrlenW(filepath), nullptr, nullptr);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    uint8_t *start1 = file_buffer + end_locaition.QuadPart - invalid_newline_count - 1;
    uint8_t *start2 = file_buffer + end_locaition.QuadPart - 1;

    for (; start1 - file_buffer >= 0; --start1, --start2)
    {
        start2[0] = start1[0];
        if (start1[0] == '\n')
        {
            if (start1 - 1 <= file_buffer || start1[-1] != '\r')
            {
                *--start2 = '\r';
            }

        }
    }

    /* cleanup */
    UnmapViewOfFile(file_buffer);
    CloseHandle(memory_mapped_file);
    CloseHandle(file);
}



void __cdecl mainCRTStartup()
{
    int argc;
    wchar_t **const argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc) + 1;
    --argc;

    enum mode
    {
        mode_overwrite = 0x0,
        mode_create_file = 0x1,
    } current_mode = { mode_overwrite };

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {

        if (lstrcmpW(argv[i], L"-o") == 0)
        {
            current_mode = mode_overwrite;
        }
        else if (lstrcmpW(argv[i], L"-n") == 0)
        {
            current_mode = mode_create_file;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (current_mode)
            {
                case mode_overwrite:
                    unix2dos2(argv[i]);
                    break;
                case mode_create_file:
                    if (lstrcmpW(argv[i], argv[i + 1]) != 0)
                    {
                        unix2dos1(argv[i], argv[i + 1]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unix2dos2(argv[i]);
                    }
                    ++i;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    /* free memory and exit */
    LocalFree(argv - 1);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

to build the code use

```
cl.exe -nologo -Oi -GS -Gs9999999 unix2dos.c -link -subsystem:console -nodefaultlib kernel32.lib shell32.lib -stack:0x100000,0x100000
```

Comment: Is this still part of your challenge not to use anything from the standard library?

Comment: Also, the documentation of the dos2unix tool mentions it can be built with MSVC, see: https://sourceforge.net/p/dos2unix/dos2unix/ci/master/tree/dos2unix/INSTALL.txt

Comment: Yes it is still part of my challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Overall design**

Code makes heavy use of data as a file with a known size.  I'd favor a stream approach where the conversion is done as data arrives and then written, negating the need for any large buffers.

**mode_overwrite design**

In my opinion, re-writing a file should not destroy the original until after the new file is *completely* written.

I'd favor writing to a temporary new file first, rename files and then destroy the original.

Should an error occur in the process, far easier to still have the original file around for recovery.

**Memory mapping**

The use of `CreateFileMappingW()` after walking the entire file with `newline_count()` reduces the benefit of mapping.  It would make more sense to map the file and then read it for `CR/LF`.

**Logic error**

In `newline_count()`, there is no need for the 2nd. `SetFilePointerEx()`.

`newline_count()` is also amiss in re-reading the the last character of the buffer into `buffer[0]`.  What should be in `buffer[0]` is the last value from the previous block read.

**Pointer computation error**

`start1 - 1` is invalid (UB) to compute when `start1 == src_file_buffer`.  Instead

```
// start1 - 1 <= src_file_buffer
start1 <= src_file_buffer + 1
```

**Access is UB**

`start1[-1]` is UB when `start1 == src_file_buffer`.

**Confusing error message**

`SetFilePointerEx()` may report "Error: could not read file", yet the error is not in reading, but seeking.

**Avoid error prone magic numbers**

Rather than `..., L"Error: could not resize ", 24, ...`

```
wchar_t err[] = L"Error: could not resize ";
... err, sizeof err / sizeof err[0],...
```

Or other self-calculating code.

**Potential out of range access**

`argv[i + 1]` is attempted without knowing `i + 1 < argc`.

**Minor**

`locaition` --> `location`

Comment: the extra `SetFilePointerEx()` is needed because by reading chunks you could end up only reading part of an EOL which would cause a false positive when reading the next chunk.

Comment: also even if `start1 == src_file_buffer` is true `start1[-1]` would not be evaluated in that case because of short circuiting.

Answer (score 3):

It takes some time to navigate through all the error logging to reach the code that actually does the line ending conversion.

Avoiding standard library functions doesn't mean you can't write some utility functions yourself, like a wrapper around `WriteConsoleW` to prevent passing all those arguments throughout the code.